# How to import contacts TO a Samsung T379 Gravity texting phone?

Tags: bluetooth, data-transfer

I have a stack of vcf files (from an old phone) to get into this new Samsung T379 gravity phone.

I have tried the samsung kies and smartswitch apps, which claim not to support this phone.

I have tried bluetooth. I can get the vcf files to the phone, but cannot get the vcf files into contacts (and I don't know where they are on the phone).

Source of vcf files: Windows 10 laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not yet found a way from win 10, but I did find a way from phone to phone via bluetooth....  why can a dumb phone send a contact via bluetooth, but I can't figure out how in win10?